# Como ordenar las filas de una matriz por el dato de una columna en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordenamiento

Necesito ordenar las filas de una matriz de python por el dato de cada columna. Por ejemplo:

```
matriz = [['foo1', 'foo1', 45],['foo2', 'foo2', 25],['foo3', 'foo3', 68],['foo4', 'foo4', 12]]
```

Lo que quiero es que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
matriz = [['foo4', 'foo4', 12], ['foo2', 'foo2', 25], ['foo1', 'foo1', 45], ['foo3', 'foo3', 68]]
```

Solo he encontrado matrices con solo numeros, y dudo si se puede hacer con una matriz con datos compuestos.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Quieres ordenar los elementos de la lista tomando como referencia solo el número?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deberas especificar que elemento quieres usar para ordenar, podras hacerlo de varias manera, podras usar el [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) donde le pasaras el parametro a ordenar, devuelve una nueva lista ordenada de los elementos. Si usas reverse=True los elementos de la lista se ordenan como si se invirtiera cada comparación

```
      >>> sorted(matriz , key=lambda x: x[2]) //x[2] la posicion del que quieres 
        ordenar
      [['foo4', 'foo4', 12], ['foo2', 'foo2', 25], ['foo1', 'foo1', 45], ['foo3', 
        'foo3', 68]]

      >>> sorted(matriz , key=lambda x: -x[2])
      ['foo3','foo3', 68], ['foo1', 'foo1', 45], ['foo2', 'foo2', 25], ['foo4', 
      'foo4', 12]]
```

Tambien puedes optar por usar [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) que puede ordenar por múltiples subarreglos.

```
      from operator import itemgetter

      >>> import operator
      >>> sorted(matriz , key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
      [['foo3','foo3', 68], ['foo1', 'foo1', 45], ['foo2', 'foo2', 25], ['foo4', 
      'foo4', 12]]
```

Espero que pueda ayudarte.